# Run a background task with asp.net mvc core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, background-task

I am working on an asp.net mvc core 2 application.

I want to run a kind of cron task in background on my application which launch something every 10 minutes.
I have wrote a console application to do this but i am wondering if there is a way to put this code directly in asp.net mvc core project (Startup.cs ?)

Answer (score 1):

In ASP Core, you use `IHostedService`

See: 
[Implement background tasks in microservices with IHostedService and the BackgroundService class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice)

Answer (score 0):

It should be the same with the console application. There is a `main` function in an asp.net core application. Also, you can put it in StartUp.cs.

The only issue is if you are hosting your application in IIS for example. Usually after sometimes without incoming request, your application will be put in to sleep mode (killed) and so does your background task. So you need to verify it carefully.

Comment: Thanks but how can i check it carefully ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding something to your Startup.cs is a way this could work.

You can implement your job like that:

```
public class YourCronService: IHostedService
{

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Task.Run(TaskRoutine, cancellationToken);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sync Task stopped");
        return null;
    }

    public Task TaskRoutine()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //Do what ever you want to do all 10 Minutes

            //Wait 10 minutes till next execution
            DateTime nextStop = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
            var timeToWait = nextStop - DateTime.Now;
            var millisToWait = timeToWait.TotalMilliseconds;
            Thread.Sleep((int)millisToWait);
        }
    }
}
```

After implementing your service you just have to add the following Line of Code into your `Startup.cs` right into the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, YourCronService>();
```

If your doing it this way you should defenitly check if your server is "always on". The job won't be executed if your server is in standby-mode. An good example herefor would be an Auzure Web App. If your web-app isn't used in a while it will set into standby-mode until the next request unless you put the "always on"-feature on.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to set always-on option in iis ?

Comment: @Bob5421 I'm not sure if there is on for the site itself. If I'm right you have to turn on the feature for the whole app-pool the site is running in. You can find this under the advanced settings. Restart your webserver after changing it to make sure, the change is active

Answer (score 0):

**I have been able to do this in MVC Core with HangFire.**

[Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)

*I added Nuget Packages:*
Hangfire.AspNetCode, HangFire.Console and HangFire.SqlServer

Configure Services:

```
services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(connectionForHangFire));
```

Configure:

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
app.UseHangfireServer();
```